# How do I spawn mobs in SMP?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to setup a Minecraft server so I can play with fluffy dragons.

As the server admin how can I spawn mobs in SMP? Can I do it in the vanilla server? Do I have to use bukkit or a plugin?

PS: [Eggs are fun!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UCHH.png)

[image: Eggs are fun!]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of release 1.1, you can enter Creative mode and use the new "Spawn Eggs" item to produce monsters, even in vanilla.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it in bukkit with the `/mob` command.

http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/admincmd/pages/mob-commands/

http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/admincmd/

Comment: Confirmed.  You cannot spawn mobs on a vanilla server.

Answer (score 4):

I spawn eggs on my server (it's vanilla, not Bukkit!) with `/give (name) 385 (mob id)`

Answer (score 0):

There is a command and it is `/spawn [id] [quantity]` in 1.2.3 only

Comment: What are the relevant ids?

Comment: @fredley my guess is it would be the "Network IDs" found on the wiki: http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Zombie

Comment: This is specific to a mod or plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `/summon` command:

```
/summon <type of mob> X Y Z
```

Answer (score -1):

Use WorldGuard Plugin! This spawns 3 ghasts:

```
/mob ghast 3
```

By default the max amount of mobs spawnable with one command is 10. You can spawn any mob using this.

Answer (score -1):

Confirmed for 1.5

`/give [player] [item] [quanity] [type]`

So to give 4 Zombie Spawn Eggs to Joe:

`/give joe 383 4 54`