# How can I  de-spawn mobs in Minecraft multiplayer?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I ask the owners of all the servers I go to, and none of them tell me how to de-spawn mobs. I'm the only admin in my server, and there are a lot of magma cubes. I want to know how to get rid of them.

Comment: If you don't mind, I'm gonna edit this to just be about de-spawning mobs. For how to spawn them, see: [How do I spawn mobs in SMP?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/38883/118)

Answer (score 13):

**In Vanilla Servers**

There are no commands for this. You could try unloading the chunk by leaving it and come back to see if they are still there (reloading the server while away from the chunk could help also.)  Or you could just simply change your game mode to creative by doing `/gamemode (c, 1, or creative)`  to spawn items, then just kill all of them with a diamond sword or whatever you please.

**In Bukkit Servers**

There are many useful plugins for bukkit that allow for simple mob killing. WorldEdit and Essentials allow for the use of `/butcher` which kills all aggressive mobs (maybe all mobs) around you. If you are unsure if a plugin has a mob killing command, just read the help page in the server or find a website with all the commands and their uses.

Answer (score 4):

In Minecraft 1.8 or newer, you can use the command `/kill @e[type=Zombie]` to kill all zombies in the world. You can also relpace Zombie with whatever mob/entity you want and it will kill it.

Comment: Worth noting: On a Minecraft 1.7.x server, `/kill ...` kills YOU.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to what [James said](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/85444/5029), you can get rid of them by restarting the server on peaceful.

Stop the server, then swing by `server.properties` and set `difficulty=0` and for good measure, 

`spawn-monsters=false`.

Restart the server, then if you wish, stop it again and set `difficulty` and `spawn-monsters` back how they were.

(Granted, this assumes you have file-system access, but since you're the admin, you might)

Answer (score 1):

Turn gamemode into peaceful! it makes no Hostile mobs!

Answer (score -2):

There is no way to "de-spawn" but a simple `/killall` command should kill any mobs in maximum render distance.** It will end up like this:

```
/killall
Killed ###
```

However, the second you do that normal mobs (zombies, skeletons, creepers) will spawn in to replace the killed ones. If those magma cubes spawned naturally then you can't do anything but continually kill them.

** = mobs killed by `/killall` will not drop any experience orbs or items.

Comment: Doesn't this kill all players?

Comment: As of now (v1.2.4), there is no such [command](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Command) in the vanilla Minecraft Server.

Comment: `/kill all` command will only kill you. There is no command on vanilla servers for killing mobs, unless you run a mod for it.

Answer (score -2):

If you just want to kill one type of mob:

`/killall <mob name> Ex: /killall spiders`

If you want to kill all mobs:

`/killall`

Comment: No such command in 1.2.5

Comment: Are you using a mod?